# Difference between HFS & HFS+ in mac

Tags: macos, filesystems, hfs+, hfs

Ive been searching around for the differences between hfs and hfs+ filesystems for mac computers , 
And found some info on them,
Wondering if any1 can provide me with some sources to gather some info  on them or even provide me with some basic info on the difference between them in terms of complexity , performance , dataStructures used etc..

Comment: Wikipedia is a pretty good high level source..

Answer (score 0):

[TechNote 1150](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html) is the closest thing to a definitive reference published by Apple.